# How to combine to LangChain Documents?

Tags: json, typescript, langchain

I want to ingest PDFs and Transcripts of a video into my Pinecone-Vectorestore.
Here is the code snippet for reading the PDF documents and creating a Document:

```
    const directoryLoaderPDF = new DirectoryLoader(filePath, {
      '.pdf': (path) => new CustomPDFLoader(path),
    });

    // const loader = new PDFLoader(filePath);
    const rawPDFs = await directoryLoaderPDF.load();

    /* Split text into chunks */
    const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
      chunkSize: 1000,
      chunkOverlap: 200,
    });

    var docs = await textSplitter.splitDocuments(rawPDFs);
```

This works fine!
Now I create a json-File that contains several transcripts of videos:

```
    const loaderJSON = new JSONLoader(
      'path',
    );

    const transcripts = await loaderJSON.load();
```

That also works, but if I know would like to combine both Documents into one I start to struggle. Currently I create an array and just add both `transcripts`and `docs` to it:

```
    var documents: any[] = [docs, transcripts];
```

Unfortunately, if I try to ingest this into my Pinecone-Vectorstore I get an error. Here the code snippet for ingesting the documents into Pinecone:

```
    await PineconeStore.fromDocuments(documents, embeddings, {
      pineconeIndex: index,
      namespace: PINECONE_NAME_SPACE,
      textKey: 'text',
    });
```

If I try to ingest `documents` to the Pinecone-Index I get:

```
    error [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading             
    'replaceAll')]
```

Currently `documents` is an array, consisting out of two separate arrays which again are storing several documents (PDF documents or transcripts). I would like to have an array that consist only of the documents (PDFs and transcripts).

Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I forgot to add the error: "error [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceAll')]" I assume PineconeStore.fromDocuments() expects a Type Document by currently I try to ingest an Array that consist out of two Documents[]